# find the example that $\bigcap\limits _n A_n$ is not connected?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

> Give an example  of  a  sequence  $(A_n)$  of connected subset   of $\mathbb{R}^2$  such that   $A_{n+1}   \subset A_n$ for  $n \in  \mathbb{N} $  but $\bigcap\limits_n A_n$ is not connected

My attempt : I take  $A_n=(-\frac{1}{n}-1,\frac{1}{n}+1)$ but $\bigcap\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} (-\frac{1}{n}-1,\frac{1}{n}+1) = (-1,1).$ which is  connected

Actually im not able to  find  the  example  that  $\bigcap\limits _n A_n$ is not connected?

Comment: I think you need your sets to be subsets of $\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: In your attempt you have $A_n\subset\Bbb R$. There is no valid example in $\Bbb R$; the question talks about $A_n\subset \Bbb R^2$.

Comment: thanks u @DavidC.Ullrich  i missed that logics